# es6 class cannot read property of this

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Here is my code

```
class ModuleController {

  constructor() {
    this.testVar = 'XYZ';
  }

  create(req, res, next) {
    debug(this.testVar);
  }
}
export default ModuleController;
```

I get `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` Why?

This is node 7 with Babel and Express -- all latest version.

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on how `create` is called.

Comment: works for me at http://ideone.com/OntsxO

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even use `create` anywhere. Show us how you call the class.

Comment: In JavaScript, `this` refers to the current context, nothing more. I suspect you are calling `create()` with some kind of closure being utilized, so `this` has different execution context than you expect.

Comment: @Bergi --- here's how I call it:-

`const Module = new ModuleController();
const router = express.Router();
router.route('/').post(Module.create); // we assume when we call a function router invokes req, res, next into it.`

Comment: @agm1984 and others --- you guys are absolutely right. My call of the function is wrong. 
It should be called as 

`router.route('/')..post((req, res, next) => Module.create(req, res, next));`

Comment: @MithunDas Yes, that's the problem. See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi just solved it, see my comments

Comment: Thank you all... its really nice to hear from you guys :)

Comment: If you encounter similar later on, investigate `.bind()`. You can bind to another object's context. I personally consider that pretty dirty however in node.js, unless you are making a bound/exotic function.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who have minimal knowledge ES6 classes and their use and come up here with this kind of a problem...
As the others said in the comments --- the way I am calling the class method was faulty...
Initially I did..

```
Module = new ModuleController(); 
const router = express.Router(); 
router.route('/').post(Module.create);
```

Which is obviously wrong... the correct way is:-

```
Module = new ModuleController(); 
const router = express.Router(); 
router.route('/').post((req, res, next) => Module.create(req, res, next));
```